# SPRING-SECURITY Credential is not supported if the CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ is ‘*’

Tags: spring-security, spring-websocket, sockjs, stompjs

I have my service work and deployed with no problem, but i need to add more feature **[Realtime Notification]**. I'm using **SockJS**, **StompJS**, **Spring security**, and **LDAP authentication**.

Here is my **AuthenticationFilter**, i'm using token as my passcode it generated after login into LDAP.

```
@Log4j2
public class AuthenticationFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

  @Autowired
  private JWTUtil jwtUtil;

  private final String authHeader = "token";

  @Override
  protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws ServletException, IOException {

    //CORS
    response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    if (request.getHeader("Access-Control-Request-Method") != null && "OPTIONS".equalsIgnoreCase(request.getMethod())) {
        response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "token");
        response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type");
        response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE");
    }

    final String authHeader = request.getHeader(this.authHeader);

    if (authHeader != null) {
        String token = authHeader;
            try {
                Claims claims = jwtUtil.getAllClaimsFromToken(token);

                List<SimpleGrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<>();

                UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authentication = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                    new User(claims.getSubject()),
                    null,
                    authorities
                );
                authentication.setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request));
                SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                log.debug("Error ", e);
            }
    }

    if (!request.getMethod().equalsIgnoreCase("OPTIONS")) {
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
  }
}
```

Here is my **WebSecurityConfig**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

  @Bean
  public UnauthorizedHandler unauthorizedHandler() throws Exception {
    return new UnauthorizedHandler();
  }

  @Bean
  public ForbiddenHandler forbiddenHandler() throws Exception {
    return new ForbiddenHandler();
  }

  @Bean
  public AuthenticationFilter authenticationFilterBean() throws Exception {
    return new AuthenticationFilter();
  }

  @Override
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
    httpSecurity
        // we don't need CSRF because our token is invulnerable
        .csrf().disable()

        .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(unauthorizedHandler()).and()
        .exceptionHandling().accessDeniedHandler(forbiddenHandler()).and()

        // don't create session
        .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and()

        .authorizeRequests()

        // allow auth url
        .antMatchers("/login","/v2/api-docs", "/configuration/ui", "/swagger-resources/**", "/configuration/**", "/swagger-ui.html", "/webjars/**", "/notif/**", "/mealnotif/**", "/topic/**", "/websocket/**", "/resources/**", "/META-INF/resources/**").permitAll()


        .anyRequest().authenticated();

    // custom JWT based security filter
    httpSecurity.addFilterBefore(authenticationFilterBean(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);

    // disable page caching
    httpSecurity.headers().cacheControl();
  }
}
```

And the last one is my **WebSocketConfig**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig implements WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

  @Override
  public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
    config.enableSimpleBroker("/topic");
    config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/mealnotif");
  }

  @Override
  public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
    registry.addEndpoint("/notif").setAllowedOrigins("*")
            .withSockJS();
  }

}
```

But in return My Angular project always return Cross-Origin Request Blocked

[CORS Reason ERROR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mkPF7.png)

How do i solve this?

Answer (score 1):

i can solve this by adding whitelist of allowed origin in my application.properties

```
management.endpoints.web.cors.allowed-origins=http://localhost,http://localhost:4200
```

by this properties i managed to giving properly response to client

[response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g6R5Y.png)